# In Twitter Bootstrap is there a way to detect the screen width (xs,sm,md,lg) without using media queries?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

Say I want my footer to be orange for XS resolutions.

I can of course write a media query to do this.

```css
@media (max-width:767px) {
 .footer {
   background-color:orange;  
 } 
}
```

But this is kind of cumbersome.  It would be nice if there was another way of doing this without using a media query?

Say a bootstrap option of "enable breakpoint wrappers".  This would use js to apply say wrapper-sm or wrapper-lg to the body tag which I could use as a descender.

eg

```css
.wrapper-sm .footer {
  background-color:orange;  
}
```

Does such a mechanism or something similar exist?

If not, is there a clever way to facilitate this with LESS (or js)?

Comment: Basically..."NO". If there were, wouldn't  Bootstrap use those instead?

Comment: no.. and you can write that kind of wrapper very easily, just use resize listener and add class "*-sm, .." to body for example

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a media query?

Comment: Locke...it just is an organizational thing.  I think it makes the stylesheets look nicer to not use media queries more than need be.  That's not to say I won't use them, but it is is nice to have alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...or you can write your own classes inside media queries and use those instead, for example:

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
  .wrapper-sm {
    background-color:orange;
  }
}
```

...and then simply apply it on your class as you asked for.

..and do the same for the other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to write a wrapper for it, but why would you do that? 
I want to recommend **SASS** if it is because of your overview. You can use multiple files for different screen-sizes.

Comment: Curious...can you elaborate?  I'm not familiar with SASS.